# Копирование массива в массив с помощью функции memcpy

Tags: c, буферизация

Нужно скопировать элементы одного массива в другой с помощью функции memcpy.помогите пожалуйста. не могу разобраться до конца с этой функцией

```c
typedef struct {
  size_t first;
  size_t last;
  uint8_t data[BUFFER_SIZE];
}
CircularBuffer;

size_t BufMoveFast(CircularBuffer * pDest, CircularBuffer * pSource) {
  size_t resuk = 0;
  resuk = GetLenghtBuf(pSource);
  printf("Length:");
  printf("%d\n", resuk);
  memcpy((char*)pSource, (char*)pDest + 3, 4 * resuk);
  return resuk;
}

ClearBuf(&bufferA);
ClearBuf(&bufferB);

WriteByte(&bufferA, 4);
WriteByte(&bufferA, 5);

WriteByte(&ufferB, 1);
WriteByte(&bufferB, 2);
WriteByte(&bufferB, 3);

printf("BufferA before move:");
PrintBuffer(&bufferA);
printf("BufferB before move:");
PrintBuffer(&bufferB);

size_t res = BufMoveFast(&bufferB, &bufferA);
printf("BufMoveSlow moved %zu item(s) from BufferA to BufferB\n", res);

size_t GetLenghtBuf(CircularBuffer* pBuf)
{
  return (pBuf->last - pBuf->first) & (BUFFER_SIZE - 1);
}

bool WriteByte(CircularBuffer* pBuf, uint8_t value)
{
  size_t next = (pBuf->last + 1) & (BUFFER_SIZE - 1);
  if (next == pBuf->first)
    return false;
  pBuf->data[pBuf->last] = value;
  pBuf->last = next;
  return true;
}
```

Comment: А зачем вы делаете +3 к pDest?

Comment: Честно говоря я практически понятия не имею как пользоваться этой функцией. Думал для того чтоб копировало в этот буфер не с первого элемента

Comment: Вы расскажите, чего вы хотите добиться

Comment: в pSource записан массив из двух чисел 4 и 5. их нужно записать в pDest после значений которые в нем имеются(1,2,3). но это нужно сделать с помощью функции memcpy.

Comment: Нужны функции `WriteByte` и `GetLenghtBuf` (код) для понимания сложности задачи.

Comment: Вот.
bool WriteByte(CircularBuffer* pBuf, uint8_t value)
{
  size_t next = (pBuf->last + 1) & (BUFFER_SIZE - 1);
  if (next == pBuf->first)
    return false;
  pBuf->data[pBuf->last] = value;
  pBuf->last = next;
  return true;
}
size_t GetLenghtBuf(CircularBuffer* pBuf)
{
  return (pBuf->last - pBuf->first) & (BUFFER_SIZE - 1);
}

Comment: Отредактировал.

Comment: Что вы хотите здесь сделать: `size_t next = (pBuf->last + 1) & (BUFFER_SIZE - 1);`

Comment: Я понял, у него **BUFFER_SIZE** = 2 ^ n

Comment: @Cerbo Прикол битового обнуления . `100000000b & (100000000b - 1) = 100000000b & 11111111b = 0`

Comment: @AlexGlebe По поводу буфера - вы правы

Comment: @ВладТамченко Лучше так `size_t next = (pBuf->last + 1) % BUFFER_SIZE;`. Понятнее и главное нет ограничения на значение `BUFFER_SIZE`.

Answer (score 2):

С функцией **memcpy** всё просто, ( куда , откуда , байт ) .

```
memcpy( pDestp , Source , sizeof(CircularBuffer) );
```

Этот вариант упрощённый, не смотрит на размер буфера текущий. Если хотите чуток сэкономить то остаток буфера не копировать можно так:

```
memcpy( pDestp , Source , ((Source->data)+(Source->last)) - Source );
```

Для добавления данных нужно чуток поработать.

```
memcpy( (pDestp->data)+(pDestp->last) , (Source->data)+(Source->first) ,
       (Source->last)-(Source->first) );
pDestp->last += ((Source->last)-(Source->first));
```

Comment: Не надо намеками прямо пишите в чем проблема.

Comment: А сделать чтобы учитывался текущий размер буфера?Сейчас же копирует затирая значения буфера в который копирует

Comment: Спасибо большое. Все работает